How to restrict RDP to only VPN users/connections?
I know that this question has been asked frequently but the answers don't work or are too general or vague. I would like to limit RDP to my Windows 2022 server to VPN connections by using the firewall. Is that possible?
I have tried adding Scope to the User Mode TCP-IN and UDP-IN default Remote Desktop firewall rules. I have tried adding the IP range I use in the VPN server properties->IP4 tab to the firewall rules mentioned, but then I lock myself out. I have tried both local (correct) and remote (incorrect) but neither accomplishes my goal.
So the scenario is that I connect to VPN, then open RDP to connect to my server. My assumption is that after connecting to VPN, I am assigned one of the IP4 addresses I configured in RRAS. So those addresses would be the ones to allow in to RDP. Do I need a new rule beyond the 2 i tried to hijack?

It sounds like both your VPN (RRAS) and RDP services are running on the same server - for my answer I have assumed that to be true - if not please disregard my answer, as it won't work for you.
Also note I am answering this generically, since my knowledge of Windows VPN's is somewhat limited.

Computers have interfaces, your typically laptop probably has 3 active interfaces, specifically:

The wired network port.
A wireless interface.
A loopback interface.

Each interface will be assigned an IP address, 127.0.0.1 for the loopback and two IP's on your home lan (probably 192.168.1.??).
When you setup a VPN both your client (laptop) and the server get an additional interface, each with an additional IP address, lets say that after you connect to the VPN:

The VPN Server has IP address: 172.16.1.1/24
Your laptop gets: 172.16.1.2


RDP is just a service that listens for connections on a particular TCP port (typically 3389). Often services "bind" the wildcard address, as a result they will accept incoming connections on any interface.
However you can reconfigure services to only accept connections on a specific IP address (bind a specific IP address)
Assuming that you don't have some complex routing requirements, this is probably the simplest solution to your problem; change which IP address RDP is binding to, to the IP address of the VPN interface (172.16.1.1 in my example).
